# Getting json url links (Youtube) to show using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json, youtube, angularjs-http

I'm trying to use AngularJS to get data from a json file which has video objects. However, I can only figure out based on other resources/references how to take ONE specific url and concatenate it using $sce to the `http://youtube.com/embed/` link. I want to be able to store links to multiple videos in a json file and be able to get those links and insert them into the text provided below. I want to be able to insert something within the $scope.video = ... of the bottom set of code, but I can't figure out what to place there.

I know I need to make an $http request, something similar to this in order to get the data:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('json/data.json').then(function(resource) {
      $scope.videoList = resource.items;
    });
```

**json/data.json** looks like this:

```js
{
  "items": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Fall Afresh",
    "url": "8VdXLM8H-xU",
    "width": 420,
    "height": 315,
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "http://youtube.com/"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Furious",
    "url": "bhBs1_iCF5A",
    "width": 420,
    "height": 315,
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "http://youtube.com/"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "God of the Redeemed",
    "url": "m1n_8MUHZ0Q",
    "width": 420,
    "height": 315,
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "http://youtube.com/"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Be Enthroned",
    "url": "98cNpM-yh-I",
    "width": 420,
    "height": 315,
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "http://youtube.com/"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "This is Amazing Grace",
    "url": "Bn5zk3yCRr0",
    "width": 420,
    "height": 315,
    "type": "video",
    "provider_name": "http://youtube.com/"
  }]
}
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.video = 'H_TnSwrNeWY';
});

myApp.directive('angularYoutube', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      video: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:300px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log('here');
      scope.$watch('video', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>Display JSON Data using AngularJS</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <!-- load angular via CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">JSON Data with AngularJS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <div ng-controller="mainController">
      <angular-youtube video="video">
      </angular-youtube>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues in code shown.

Use `ng-src` on the iframe to prevent bad requests when url is not available

To access the data inside the $http `resource` object you need to first access the `data` property

```
$scope.videoList = resource.data.items;
```

As a start point you could then set the first video by doing:

```
$scope.video = resource.data.items[0].url; // or $scope.videoList[0].url
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fn5uu0LJwqzbElcjTcGM?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much! What you gave me helped me to figure out how to loop through the array to grab all the videos. I created a div using ng-repeat in the HTML to grab all the data.item urls.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet is erroneous:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('json/data.json').then(function(resource) {
      //ERRONEOUS
      //$scope.videoList = resource.items;
      //USE INSTEAD
      $scope.videolist = resource.data.items;
    });
```

An http promise returns a response object:

```
$http(...).
  then(function onSuccess(response) {
    // Handle success
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  }, function onError(response) {
    // Handle error
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  });
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- General Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Answer (score 0):

I now solved how to repeat through the JSON array of objects to show all the videos using this within the HTML:

```html
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <div ng-repeat="x in videoList">
    <angular-youtube video="x.url">
    </angular-youtube>
  </div>
</div>
```

This allowed me to grab the data where $scope.videoList is located and pull the urls from each one to display.